# A question about overloading a boolean operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For this assignment, we are not allowed to use std::string.

I have a constructor that takes in a C-string modeled after a DNA strand.

```
DNAStrand::DNAStrand(const char* startingString) {
    length = strlen(startingString);
    bases = new char[length + 1] {'A','C','G','T',0};
}
```

I then attempted to overload a boolean operator that would check the strand I created against another one.

```
bool DNAStrand::operator==(const DNAStrand& other) const {
    if (length != other.length)
        return false; //can't be the same if we don't have same # items

    //Same size, walk through items looking for mismatch
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (bases[i] != other.bases[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true; //Must be identical
}
```

When I attempt to test it using the line of code below, however, `isMatch3` returns true.

```
DNAStrand str2("AACC");
bool isMatch3 = (str2 == DNAStrand("AAGC"));
```

I'm pretty sure that there's an issue with the for loop where it's supposed to iterate over each char in the C-string, but I can't figure out what the issue is. In my mind, it's either that or my original constructor is wrong.

Comment: Please just use `std::string` instead of `char*`/`char[]`/`new` for strings and you won't have any such problems.

Comment: Have you forgotten to set bases to whatever is actually in your starting String?
At the moment it looks like no matter what you pass to the constructor, the bases will be {'A','C','G','T',0}

Comment: @walnut Edited for clarity that we are not allowed to use std::string for this assignment to "learn about what is involved in making a string-like object and do [our] own memory management"

Comment: @DanBoing ok, It can't be helped then. Just be aware that you would not write code like that in practice.

Comment: Voting to close as typo, since `bases` is clearly always initialized with the same value, which does not seem to be intended.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `DNAStrand` object you are not storing `startingString` anywhere (you only keep its length). Even more, you are setting the same base "ACGT" to all you objects:

```
DNAStrand::DNAStrand(const char* startingString) {
    length = strlen(startingString);
    bases = new char[length + 1] {'A','C','G','T',0};
}
```

When you compare `bases` in your loop you are comparing "ACGT" in both left and right objects, and always returns `true`.

Solve it storing `startstring`:

```
DNAStrand::DNAStrand(const char* startingString) {
    length = strlen(startingString);
    bases = new char[length + 1] {startingString};
}
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C++. A `char` array cannot be initialized from a `const char*`.